# How can I change the case of a pgfkeys option dynamically within the name of a macro invoked on the fly?

Tags: expansion, pgfkeys, uppercase

I hope I am describing this correctly. In a larger project, I am trying to make my document level commands CamelCase and this is proving difficult when using keys and values, intended to be used dynamically in invoking commands, are all lowercase. I am sure this is an expandability issue but I am just not seeing the solution. I have searched the site and cannot find an example that I see as obviously relevant here.

In the MWE, the commands `\AlwaysDogHere`, `\AlwaysCatHere`, and `\AlwaysBotHere`  are normally in the preamble but I've moved them into the document so their results can be easily seen. The `typeout{}` output is correct but the relevant command isn't being correctly constructed dynamically, and that is my problem. See comments in the MWE. Everything works as long as the document commands are all lowercase like the keys and values.

My attempt:

```
% !TEX program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\pgfkeys{%
  /mwe/optiond/.cd,
  initial@setup/.style={%
    /mwe/options/mwe@example/.initial=dog,
  },%
  initial@setup,%
  mykey/.is choice,
  mykey/.default=cat,
  mykey/dog/.style={/mwe/options/mwe@example=dog},
  mykey/cat/.style={/mwe/options/mwe@example=cat},
  mykey/bot/.style={/mwe/options/mwe@example=bot},
}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\AlwaysDogHere}{}{%
  % This command does something related to dog.
  %\relax
  Dog
}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\AlwaysCatHere}{}{%
  % This command does something related to cat.
  %\relax
  Cat
}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\AlwaysBotHere}{}{%
  % This command does something related to bot.
  %\relax
  Bot
}%
% The key should be lowercase in the \typeout{} output.
\typeout{}%
\typeout{Working with \pgfkeysvalueof{/mwe/options/mwe@example}}%
\typeout{}%

\begin{document}
Hello.
% I need the key's first letter to be capitalized in the 
% next line so the correct macro will be invoked dynamically
% in situ.
\csname Always\MakeUppercase\expandafter\expandafter\pgfkeysvalueof{/mwe/options/mwe@example}  Here\endcsname%

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can only `\csname Always\MakeUppercase`   in a 2022 latex (in case you need to support older formats0

Comment: `\MakeUppercase\expandafter` is `\MakeUppercase{\expandafter}` with just `\expandafter` as the argument

Comment: Yes indeed I'm aware of the format support. The MWE doesn't work; it was just the most recent attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were calling `\Alwaysdog Here` with `d` and a space, You can fully expand using `\expanded` (note `\MakeUppercase` here require a 2022 LateX)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\pgfkeys{%
  /mwe/optiond/.cd,
  initial@setup/.style={%
    /mwe/options/mwe@example/.initial=dog,
  },%
  initial@setup,%
  mykey/.is choice,
  mykey/.default=cat,
  mykey/dog/.style={/mwe/options/mwe@example=dog},
  mykey/cat/.style={/mwe/options/mwe@example=cat},
  mykey/bot/.style={/mwe/options/mwe@example=bot},
}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\AlwaysDogHere}{}{%
  % This command does something related to dog.
  %\relax
  Dog
}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\AlwaysCatHere}{}{%
  % This command does something related to cat.
  %\relax
  Cat
}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\AlwaysBotHere}{}{%
  % This command does something related to bot.
  %\relax
  Bot
}%
% The key should be lowercase in the \typeout{} output.
\typeout{}%
\typeout{Working with \pgfkeysvalueof{/mwe/options/mwe@example}}%
\typeout{}%

\begin{document}
Hello.
% I need the key's first letter to be capitalized in the 
% next line so the correct macro will be invoked dynamically
% in situ.

\expandafter\show\csname Always\MakeUppercase\expandafter\expandafter\pgfkeysvalueof{/mwe/options/mwe@example}  Here\endcsname


\expandafter\show\csname Always\expanded{\noexpand\MakeUppercase\pgfkeysvalueof{/mwe/options/mwe@example}}Here\endcsname

\csname Always\expanded{\noexpand\MakeUppercase\pgfkeysvalueof{/mwe/options/mwe@example}}Here\endcsname

\end{document}
```

Comment: Aha. I didn't know about `\expanded` and `\noexpand`.  Let me see if this works in the larger project. Thank you!

Comment: It works. I will learn more about `\expanded` and `\noexpand` today.